# Missing Vim registry `*` on Windows 10 WSL? Not really :)

Tags: vim, windows-subsystem-for-linux

For the bare version of Vim that comes with WSL on Windows 10, attempts to "yank to registry `*`" will fail with the following error message:

[image]

One way to reproduce the symptom is to assign the following mapping, and invoke it by pressing `Y` in normal mode.

```
nnoremap Y :let @* = expand("%:p")<CR>
```

Comment: Please [do not edit your original question to include an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216722/271445).

Comment: This question has been marked duplicate; and there is no way to submit an answer.

Comment: Kept what I've learned in the body of the question, for documentation. Thank for pointing out  @TwistyImpersonator

Comment: If you wish to submit an answer, then either your question is not a duplicate (in which case you should edit it to indicate why not), or you can submit the answer to the marked duplicate question. Thanks for contributing.

Comment: The challenge is, the [marked duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/1291425/windows-subsystem-linux-make-vim-use-the-clipboard) is not truly a duplicate: it is about how to let Vim write to the Windows OS's clipboard. My original question is about letting Vim to write to its own `*` registry. @Ingo Karkat, please lift the embargo.

Comment: you need to edit your question and clearly explain why it's not a duplicate. Then it can be reopened.

Comment: Have you actually tried the solution (https://superuser.com/a/1345241/117820; i.e. installing VcXsrv)? The registers `*` and `+` both require a connection to the X server.

Comment: That notwithstanding, I've also reopened this question. Please edit and new facts and findings into the question; I'm sceptical that it will attract answers in the current form.

Comment: Thank you for lifting the embargo, and getting me a chance to make the QA readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short solution

In reference to the discussion [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1291425/windows-subsystem-linux-make-vim-use-the-clipboard), installing a "full" version of Vim through `apt-get install vim-gtk` solves the trouble.

### Longer explanation

WSL on Windows 10 is shipped with the basic version of Vim, which does not have clipboard support.

- To verify this, executing `:echo has('clipboard')` will yield `0`.

Installing the `vim-gtk` equips Vim with the `clipboard` functionality.