# Window subsytem for linux (WSL) copy to clipboard from the command line?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, clipboard

I like to use utilities like [pbpaste](https://ss64.com/osx/pbpaste.html) on mac and [xclip](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22494/copy-file-to-xclip-and-paste-to-firefox) on linux to copy from the command line to the clipboard. I'm using [windows system for linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install) (WSL). Is there any way of getting this behaviour from WSL. That is, I want a command line `CLIP` so that if I run the following in a WSL linux command line the output is written to clipboard:

```
ls | CLIP
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use clipboard through WSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/1618537/use-clipboard-through-wsl).  Just a reminder to always search for an existing question/answer before asking a new one.  While I understand that sometimes they are hard to find, this was the first result when searching the site for "wsl clipboard".  Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... not sure how I missed that. I tired that clip.exe command before and it didn't work. But let me retry when I'm back on my windows machine. Shall we close this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Wait until you try it out - It does need the `.exe` extension on it, so maybe that's what you missed?  But yes, if that works, I'd recommend accepting that other answer as the duplicate.  Thanks!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You may call Windows executables in WSL, only that you need the full
file-name:

```
ls | clip.exe
```

Note that, unlike under Windows, the `.exe` part is required in WSL.

Comment: How about CLIP.EXE vs clip.exe? (Curious!)

Comment: @Hannu: Just tried it - it works.

Comment: i.e. both works. Right the idiosyncrasies...

Comment: Unfortunately, `clip.exe` absolutely wrecks anything that's not ASCII, because Windows has not discovered UTF-8 yet. :(

Answer (score -1):

try this

```shell
ls | clipcopy
clippaste
```

can use on Windows with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: Welcome to Super User!  I'm not aware of `clipcopy` and `clippaste` being standard Linux commands.  They certainly aren't available in my Ubuntu 22.04 WSL install.  If there are additional instructions or dependencies needed for your answer to work, please edit it to include them.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, is from `oh-my-zsh`

`clipcopy is a shell function from /home/liubin/.oh-my-zsh/lib/clipboard.zsh`

if you use zsh, maybe can use it (clipboard.zsh on github)[https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/lib/clipboard.zsh]

Comment: Unfortunately, when I run `echo abcåäö | clipcopy`, the clipboard gets populated with useless junk: `abc├Ñ├ñ├╢` ☹️